# awk or grep to get a specific string in shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, awk

I am trying to get only the value of percentage part from this data which is stored in a variable also I want to get only the first percentage value that is present in the output.

```
<map id="09EhL_map" name="09EhL_map">
<area shape="poly" coords="374,274,374,274,376,274,376,274,376,274,376,274" title="5-April-2019: 0.0% of runs for TT1 were successful" alt="" nohref="nohref"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="368,274,368,274,371,274,374,274,374,274,374,274" title="4-April-2019: 20.0% of runs for TT2 were successful" alt="" nohref="nohref"/>
```

what I have done

```
var1="<map id="09EhL_map" name="09EhL_map">
<area shape="poly" coords="374,274,374,274,376,274,376,274,376,274,376,274" title="5-April-2019: 0.0% of runs for HIP-HCTP-HIP3 were successful" alt="" nohref="nohref"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="368,274,368,274,371,274,374,274,374,274,374,274" title="4-April-2019: 0.0% of runs for HIP-HCTP-HIP3 were successful" alt="" nohref="nohref"/>"

var2=$(echo var1 | grep "%")
```

This doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var2=$(echo $var1 | grep -o  [0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*%)
```

here `grep -o [0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*%` will match floating point numbers having `%` sign in the end.

In your case it will print

```
0.0%
20.0%
```

If you want to get only the first match, then use:

```
var2=$(echo $var1 | grep -o  [0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*% | head -n1)
```